# ARKit after apply force get location of node

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

Same Problem like this question  [how to track the position of a node after applying force in Arkit 1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49237546/how-to-track-the-position-of-a-node-after-applying-force-in-arkit-1-5) but unanswered  So I am adding new question

I have node (SCNSphere) in which I apply force. Node has `dynamic`  Physics body. On swipe I apply force to `SCNNode` using  `physicsBody?.applyForce` 
which all work good

Issue is after apply force as it has `dynamic` body  it is going down continuously and **I want to track that position**

on `renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval)`  I print the `position`  of `SCNNode` but it is showing the same position every time ,  why the Y position is not decreasing as it is going down side ?

Like

`<SCNNode: 0x280f29500 'ball' pos(-0.165368 0.3 -0.809096) | geometry=<SCNSphere: 0x280619380 | radius=0.150> | no child>` 
`<SCNNode: 0x280f29500 'ball' pos(-0.165368 0.2 -0.809096) | geometry=<SCNSphere: 0x280619380 | radius=0.150> | no child>` 
`<SCNNode: 0x280f29500 'ball' pos(-0.165368 0.1 -0.809096) | geometry=<SCNSphere: 0x280619380 | radius=0.150> | no child>`

and so on?

How I added the node

```
        let ballWithOrientation = getNewBallNode() // return ball node + position
        let ballNode = ballWithOrientation.ball // it is the SCNNode
        self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ballNode ?? SCNNode()) // Added to the scene 
        let cameraPosition =  self.sceneView.pointOfView?.worldFront

        let target =  SCNVector3(Double(cameraPosition?.x ?? 1) * forceVector,Double (cameraPosition?.y  ?? 1) * forceVector,Double(cameraPosition?.z ?? 1) * forceVector) // Vector of direction 
        let throwSpeed = self.calculateBestThrowSpeed(origin: ballNode!.position, target:target , timeToTarget: 0.66)  Calculated vector with velocity 
        ballNode?.physicsBody?.applyForce(throwSpeed, asImpulse: true) // apply force
```

**Question**  How to track world position of SCNNode after apply force ?

Comment: Can you please share your code snippet

Comment: @K_Mohit What i did is just create scnnode and apply force do you still want to see the code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution which is very simple

```
open var presentation: SCNNode { get }
```

This property of `SCNNode`  will provide you presentation of current node

so finally `ballNode.presentation.position` will provide you current position of node with all animations (forces)

from [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1408030-presentation)

> When you use implicit animation (see SCNTransaction) to change a node’s properties, those node properties are set immediately to their target values, even though the animated node content appears to transition from the old property values to the new. During the animation SceneKit maintains a copy of the node, called the presentation node, whose properties reflect the transitory values determined by any in-flight animations currently affecting the node.

Hope it is helpfult to someone finding the similar issue